# Solving PDE by separation of variables.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, integral-equations

Let $F(x_1,x_2,u)$ be a real valued function. Consider the following PDE
$$f_1(x_1,x_2,u) \left(F-u \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\right) +f_2(x_1,x_2,u) \frac{\partial F}{\partial u} =0.$$
The solution of the above PDE is given by
$$F=\phi(x_1,x_2)\exp\left( \int \frac{f_1}{u f_1 -f_2} du\right).$$

The question is: according to the  above solution  $F$, is it possible with out loss of genrality to write  $F$  in the form
$$F=\rho(x_1,x_2) f(u), \quad \text{or} \quad F=f(\rho(x_1,x_2) u)? $$

Comment: For subscripts use an underscore `_`. For instance `a_b` outputs $a_b$.

Comment: Yes, it is possible and you just did it. Let $$f(u;c)=\exp\left(\int \frac{f_1(x_1,x_2,u)}{u\cdot f_1(x_1,x_2,u)-f_2(x_1,x_2,u)}\mathrm{d}u\right)+c$$

Comment: Thanks @K.defaoite for your response. Would you please clarify your answer a little bit? This point is very important to me.

Comment: You want a solution of the PDE in the form of $F(x_1,x_2,u)=f(x_1,x_2)g(u)$. Let $f$ be the $\phi$ mentioned in the post and let $g(u)$ be the exponential of the integral expression. In essence you've answered your own quesiton.

Comment: Yes, I got your point. What about the solution in the second form I mean $F=f(\rho(x_1,x_2)u)$?

Comment: This one is harder to nail down. Try substituting it into the PDE and see what you get out on the other side. My gut feeling tells me it won't work out nicely.

Comment: I don't think we can really say much on that topic without having certain conditions on $f_1$ and $f_2$ and the connectedness/convexity of the domain you want the solution to be in.

Comment: Just an idea comes to my mind and I think it may work. If we define a new variable $\widetilde{u}=\rho(x_1,x_2) u$ and then $d\widetilde{u}=\rho(x_1,x_2) d u$ and hence the solution will be in the form $F(x,u)=f(x) g(\rho(x)u)$. What do you think @K.defaoite? Is this can be considered the general solution?

Comment: once again it's very difficult to make any comments while leaving $f_1,f_2$ general.

Comment: The functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not general but very specific. What kind of restrictions on them are needed?

Comment: Do you have any explicit formulae for them? What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Here are the formulas:
$$f_1=\frac{(\partial_{x_1}F+u\partial_{x_2}F)F''-(\partial_{x_1}F'+u\partial_{x_2}F'-\partial_{x_2}F)F'}{2FF''},$$
$$f_2=\frac{u(\partial_{x_1}F+u\partial_{x_2}F)F''-(\partial_{x_1}F'+u\partial_{x_2}F'-\partial_{x_2}F)(uF'-F)}{2FF''}.$$
This problem from the area of Finsler geometry.

Comment: This changes the problem considerably, no? These expressions contain the function we want to solve for, $F$.